# c++ OpenGL Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, arrays, class, opengl, segmentation-fault

So, this is a part of my code.
I have a class named `Polygon` with an array to keep my coordinates.

```
class Polygon{
private:
    GLint Vertices[][2];


public:
    Polygon(){
        GLint** Vertices = new GLint*[20000];
        for (int j=0; j<20000; j++){
            Vertices[j] = new GLint[2];
        }
    }

    void setCoord(int m, GLint x, GLint y){
        Vertices[m][0] = x;
        Vertices[m][1] = y;
    }
};
```

I try to compile my code and when I try to put my first coordinates in the array in the `setCoord()` function (when m is 0), I have a segmentation fault error.

Don't know why. Hope you guys will help. Please don't tell me about vectors. I'm not familiar with this technique, and I haven't much time to learn it as my project has to be finished in 4 days.

Thank you!

Comment: You should add a destructor that deletes them at least.

Answer (score 4):

```
GLint** Vertices = new GLint*[20000];
```

is a local variable declaration in the `Polygon()` constructor, and shadows your `Vertices` class member declaration. Everything allocated there is lost (leaks) after the constructor returns.

You're accessing uninitialized memory in `setCoord()` thus it *crashes*.

Change declaration of vertices and constructor in the following way

```
class Polygon{
private:
    GLint** Vertices; // <<<<<< Change declaration


public:
    Polygon(){
        Vertices = new GLint*[20000]; // <<<<<< Remove GLint**
        for (int j=0; j<20000; j++){
            Vertices[j] = new GLint[2];
        }
    }
};
```

---

A side note

> *"Please don't tell me about vectors. I'm not familiar with this technique, and I haven't much time to learn it as my project has to be finished in 4 days."*

I'd suppose use of [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) might be far easier to learn, than getting around and handling all of the obstacles of dynamic memory management right on your own. Good luck!

Comment: Re last paragraph: using `std::vector` *is* handling dynamic memory management right :-)

Comment: Still nothing. Ok here is what i want to do. I want to create an array p of Polygons. Each p[i] (i=0,1,2,...) is a polygon. How can I do this? I'm not sure how to do this. I have tried a lot of things but still nothing. Maybe there's something else i can do. This is my first c++ program in a very long time and my very first using OpenGL.

Comment: @JamesCs15 What do you mean _"Still nothing"_? I'd suspect you might run into a lot of other errors with that style of a class, even if you fixed the errors I mentioned. Thinking about copy constructors, assignment operators etc. this will be hard to manage correctly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean the segmentation fault error is still there. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: @JamesCs15 _"What do you suggest me to do?"_ I already did: Use a `std::vector<std::vector<GLint>>`.